# Nexus 7 dealing with jQuery Mobile : input type number problems

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, nexus-7

I'm currently developping an app who is actually using an `HTML Form`, built with `jQuery mobile`. The app works great on a tablet (`version 2.3.4`), but when I installed the app on the nexus 7, I noticed that some `input texts` were'nt working (I can fill some fields but sometimes, if I fill one, the `input field` is kept **blank**).

For informations, the tablet is running on the new version of Android (`JellyBean, version 4.1.1`). I'm dealing with the version `1.7.1` of `jQuery` and version `1.1.0` of `jQuery` `mobile`.

So my question is : should I updgrade my version of `jQuery mobile` to `1.2.0` (who's experimental but supports `JellyBean`) or it's a well known bug with `jQuery` `mobile` and the Nexus 7 in general ?

Many thanks,

**EDIT** : I noticed that it appears only with number fields

Ex :

```
<label id="lbl_nozone">Area id:</label>

<input name="nozone" id="nozone" type="number" maxlength="2" style="width:70px" 
openmrs-fieldtype="" openmrs-datatype="" openmrs-class="" openmrs-concept=""/>
```

Comment: Could you post some sample of the html? I've tested my own jQuery mobile (1.1.1) app on the Nexus 7 and had no problems with input fields.

Comment: Do you have input fields with number type? I noticed that it bugs only with this type of fields

Comment: You mean as in a field that only accepts numbers? I don't have anything like that, so I suppose that may be the cause. Is this done through javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For informations, I resolved the bug. Its appears when you set a maxlength attribute to an input.

Here's the bug for the issue : [35264](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35264)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754575/jelly-bean-webview-not-working-well-with-html-maxlength-attribute-for-text-box)'s the stackoverflow response.