# Not able to use maxlength in Android JellyBean

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am facing an issue in Android which is like whenever I am using the maxlenth attribute on input e.g.  ; After entering 20 characters on android tab, that page gets hang, I am unable to delete anything or add anything in any other input, other pages works fine but not this page where I entered the charcters upto max limit

I am using on KArbonn Smart Tab 8
Android JellyBean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a well known Android 4.1 issue.

[Jelly Bean WebView not working well with HTML maxlength attribute for text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754575/jelly-bean-webview-not-working-well-with-html-maxlength-attribute-for-text-box/11767743#11767743)

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35264

Unfortunately, no fix yet. You can follow the above stack-overflow post where they have a JS fix.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer and it is working for me:

```
x$("#fieldWithMaxLength").on("keydown", function(e) {
            if(e.keyCode != 8) {
                maxlength = $(this).attr('maxlength');
                if(this.value.length >= maxlength ) {
                    var curIndex = $(this).attr('tabindex');
                    $('[tabindex=' + curIndex + ']').focus();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```